# Attempt to Work with External PHP FIle Failing and Resulting in Malformed Output

Tags: php, html

Very new to PHP; however, I have confirmed that PHP is properly configured and working with my local IIS by using it in a form within a different local site.

In this project, I have a simple HTML file that looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta charset="UTF=8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/styles.css" />
    <title>My title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 class="ctr">Header 1</h1>
      <h3 class="ctr">Header 3</h3><br /><br />
      <?php
        include "../../cgi-bin/physics_equations.php";
        echo "<p>I am in here.</p>";
        show_categories();
      ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Rather than running the function, when I open the page, I receive:

```
Header 1
Header 3

I am in here.
"; show_categories(); ?>
```

I've checked multiple times that all brackets, quotes, and the <?php tag itself are closed within my .php file, and all lines are properly ended with a semicolon. I can add that, if it'd be beneficial, but it's a couple of functions long and I don't want to clutter up the question. I feel like I must be missing something on the HTML side which is resulting in this behavior (again, very new to it), but I'm uncertain what it might be. I get exactly the same whether I put the include where it is above or at the very top of the html page.

Probably something silly but checking in here after running multiple searching for similar questions and just coming up empty handed.

Comment: `Header 1`
`Header 3`
`I am in here.`
`"; ?>`

@KenLee It looks pretty similar, and I apologize for the markdown fail.  First attempt at a comment, and I don't quite seem to have it...
I guess that does rule out something left open in the external script, though?

Comment: @KenLee If I run it directly in the browser, I just get a page saying the same `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.  If I run it in cmd as `php phpinfo.php`, though, I get a big list of information, starting with `PHP Version => 8.3.2`.

Comment: That sounds likely, although the output confuses me even if that's the case.  I did configure the Handler Mapping globally, and each site has identical listings for PHP...  Each has its own App Pool, running under the same identity, but otherwise the only difference should be the file paths and ports used to access them, as far as I can tell.  Still, running some searches for that as a lead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to simply be that I misunderstood how PHP works; it looks like the  tags can't just be plopped in the middle of an .html file and be treated as script code.  Reformatting the page as a .php page (with echoes to output HTML) ultimately worked, and I'll keep with this moving forward, unless I hit on some other information that refines my understanding.